# Software Architecture: Does Service Layer and Business Layer has their own Model

Tags: architecture, service-layer, business-layer

I am confused with designing application between Business and Service Layer.

What I get so far through researching from internet?

A service layer normally a domain specific code which serve for the presentation.

A business layer normally a domain specific code which serve for the rules of the business.

Not sure and confused because I have not directly used.

1. Does service layer allow to access data access layer by pass business layer eg. Entity Framework
2. Does service layer and business layer have their own models in between their layers? In my own knowledge, if I mixed the use with entity in entity framework, model in business/service across different layer, the code will be a mess.

Comment: Are you asking about entity framework in particular? Is this about domain driven design ? It may help to add tags.

Comment: I would say mainly the design.